# The quotient of the Weyl algebra by its centre is a matrix algebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, positive-characteristic

Consider the Weyl algebra, call it $W$, generated by $x_1,x_2,...x_n,\partial_1,\partial_2,...\partial_n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ subject to the usual relations:
$x_ix_j=x_jx_i$, $\partial_i\partial_j=\partial_j\partial_i$ and
$[\partial_i,x_j]=\delta_{ij}$ for all $i$,$j$. I want to show that the quotient of $W$ by its centre is isomorphic to some matrix algebra over $k$. I would like an explicit construction of such a matrix algebra as well as the required isomorphism. Is there any obvious way to do this? Any help, even in the $n=1$ case, will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything in the definition about a "quotient by the center". It's unclear why that would be useful anyhow, because the center isn't an ideal, and you don't get a quotient ring.  The wiki article makes it sound like it only applies to artinian rings, and the Weyl algebra is not such a ring...

Comment: The definitions I"m finding all say an azumaya algebra is one for which $A$ is a finitely generated projective faithful $R$ module, and $A\otimes_R A^{op}$ is isomorphic to a matrix algebra $M_r(R)$ for some $A$.  I don't know why you think a quotient pops up there. The center is not an ideal and therefore does not make a suitable candidate to quotient by.  Upon further reading, I've found the center is a lot larger than I expected when $p>0$!  It looks like this is true.

Comment: @rschwieb Understood! I am sorry, that was my bad! Let's consider the case of the affine line. What if I quotient it by the ideal generated by $x^p$ and $\partial^p$? My hunch is that this will become a matrix algebra. Do you think this makes sense? If so, do you see any direct way of proving it?

Comment: I've replaced my answer with what I know now. I'm falling short in a couple details.

Answer (score 0):

If the center is $k[\{x_i^p\mid i=1\ldots n\}\cup\{\partial_i^p\mid i=1\ldots n\}]$, then it seems clear that $W$ is generated by the lower powers of those generators because you can always sort them out with their commutation relations and take out powers that are too high as coefficients in the center. It clearly has to be faithful because of the multiplicative identity.

I'm not completely sure how to reason $W$ is projective. It might actually be free over its center for some basis, but it's not immediately clear to me why.

If it were free of rank $R$ over its center $R$, then it is clear that $End(A_R)\cong M_n(R)$, and $A\otimes_R A\cong R^{n\times n}$, and there's probably some basic results on Hom sets that I'm forgetting that simply says it's $M_n(R)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I basically meant that once you quotient it by its centre you get a matrix algebra. And the centre, as far as I know, is $k[x_1^p,x_2^p,...x_n^p,\partial_1^p,\partial_2^p,...\partial_n^p]$, **not** $k$.

Comment: In light of my previous comment, could you please also suggest an edit to the original question to make it "correct"?

Comment: I completely rephrased the question. Hopefully, it makes sense now. I apologise for the inconvenience!

Comment: By the way, my initial question was based on the term Azumaya algebra as used in the following:

"The sheaf $D_X$ of crystalline differential operators on a smooth variety $X$ over $k$ has a non-trivial center, canonically identified with the sheaf of functions on the Frobenius twist $T^∗X^{(1)}$ of the cotangent bundle. Moreover $D_X$ is an Azumaya algebra over $T^∗X^{(1)}$."

This is taken from page 3 (page 6 of the PDF file) of *Localisation of Modules for a semisimple Lie Algebra in prime characteristic* (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0205144.pdf) by Bezrukavnikov–Mirković–Rumynin. (ctd.)

Comment: (ctd.) I want the proof only in the case where our variety is just affine n-space. In that case, the sheaf of crystalline differential operators is just the Weyl algebra.